# Why a function (which is used as default constraint of a column in a table) cannot be changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a scalar-valued function which I need to modify. So I created a script which drops that function and then create it again.

When I run the script SQL Server gives me an error:

> Msg 3729, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserId' because it is being referenced by object 'DF__generated__creat__02D4B8E6'.

I investigated and find out that this function is being used as a default constraint for a column in a table.

```
create table generated_email
(
    generated_email_pk                  bigint                          not null identity,
    name                                varchar(64)                     not null,
    row_version                         RowVersion                      not null,
    create_user                         varchar(50) default coalesce(dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserId(),user)   not null,
    create_datetime                     datetime    default getDate()   not null,
    update_user                         varchar(50) default coalesce(dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserId(),user)   not null,
    update_datetime                     datetime    default getDate()   not null
)
```

I thought ok lets just modify the function. So I created a script which alter that function.

When I run the script SQL Server I get another error:

> Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure udf_GetCurrentUserId, Line 68
>   Cannot ALTER 'dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserId' because it is being referenced by object 'DF__generated__creat__02D4B8E6'.

Damn. So I am stuck. Why SQL Server implemented this restriction? Why it thinks that if a function is created it will never need modification?

Comment: What would happen if your function suddenly returns values that would break the constraints? What should something named "udf_getCurrentUserId" return when evaluated after a modification by you? What if your udf takes one second, and your table has a million rows? That's over 11 days time...

Comment: There's no easy way to do it.  You can script out the constraint for the `generated_email` table, drop that constraint, alter the function, and then run your previously generated script to reapply the constraint

Comment: Just drop the default constraint, alter your function, then re-add the default constraint.

Comment: There are 94 columns in 45 tables which are using this function as default constraint. Have to drop all those 94 constraints, change this function and then create all those 94 constraints again.

Comment: modifying just the logic within the function

Comment: @srh You seem to have accepted that you cannot alter a function that is used as a DEFULT constraint - only the designers of T-SQL can answer "why" - you might get better answers posting on http://dba.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

That's silly that you can't change a function when it's being used in a constraint, but it seems to be a legitimate limitation in SQL Server. You could create a function such as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserIdCaller() AS varchar(8000)
BEGIN
RETURN dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserId()
END
```

Then your work of unloading and reloading constraints gets reduced to changing all constraints to use dbo.udf_GetCurrentUserIdCaller(), and then you can edit udf_GetCurrentUserId() all you like. SQL Server does not check nested dependencies.

You can programmatically access constraint text to get the information you need to script a solution from

```
SELECT obj.name as 'Table', col.name as 'Column',object_name(default_object_id) AS [ConstraintLabel],
object_definition(default_object_id) AS [DefaultValue]
FROM   sys.objects obj INNER JOIN sys.columns col
ON obj.object_id = col.object_id
where obj.type = 'U' and object_definition(default_object_id) is not null
```